# Can we position signers by recipient id through the DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

We've set up our template to include signature blocks and we're able to send the recipient's name and email address with the envelope. These recipients appear in the recipient list and when you sign in to DocuSign you're able to select one of the recipients from the list and position it appropriately.

We're looking at removing this manual step so that we can say, for example, the first signature we send across in the envelope corresponds to signature block one in our template and the second to the second as so on.

When we create the signature blocks in our template we can assign roles and the DocuSign documentation suggests that if we send a role across with the envelope we should be able to achieve the automatic positioning that we're after.

What we're wondering is whether we can also do this with the recipient id rather than the role?

Comment: Gareth, I'm confused about what it means to position a signer.
You either mean:
1. Position of a tab for signature.
2. Routing Order. 

Can you explain what positioning a signer mean. I would think you mean #1 and then there are various ways to do that. positioning of signing tabs in the document. I can point to the APIs to do that using coordinates or using what we call anchor tags. 
But your language is confusing so you may mean something else. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to position tabs (signature blocks) for recipients.
One approach is to specific x/y coordinates where the tab should be located inside the document (also specify page #)
Another approach is to use AnchorTags which is specific text that the tab (or tag) would be located in. This can be used with white-on-white text in the document, that could be invisible to the signer but allows the tag to be placed there. This can also be a real part of the document (like 'Date:') and you can specify an offset to improve your positioning. 
Read more how to use AnchorTags in the API here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/sending-group/using-anchor-tags